# Polar : Current and latest version highcharts are not working propeller

Tags: highcharts

Current and latest version highcharts are not working propeller. v3.0.2 is working good

please see attached image and sample application.

[image]

Comment: sorry i missed adding jsfiddle links   
Working Application High chart v3.0.2  : http://jsfiddle.net/P2LS8/3/ 
Issues Application :High chart v3.0.10: http://jsfiddle.net/P2LS8/4/

Comment: It looks like a possibly bug, reported here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2804 so please stay on track with github thread.